# Facebook retrieve correct acess_tokens

Tags: php, facebook

I am having trouble finding the right access_tokens.
I have tried all ways that I have found on Google and developers.fb, but for this application(I have done it before, and made it work for another app) I just don't seem to be succesful.

I am aware that FB is constantly renewing their API's so maybe I just have found outdated solutions.

There seem to be different types of access tokens: user access tokens, and page access tokens. I find some answers in facebook documentation, but none that I understand.

The app I'm trying to create is something similar to a birthday-reminder, so it needs to be able to send offline messages(fex. be runned by a cron-job, and post to just one fb-page, owned by me, just in the name of the app itself)

I have registered the app with the page-tab on this address:
--`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP'S_ID&display=popup&next=MY_URL`--
and can now find it from the Facebook-page's settings.

Then I get to the part where i need the access token.
I dont know which of the URL's that give me what kind of access token, so I have tried both:

I have visited this URL:
(I write all links duplicate, the answer from tutorials, and my re-written link)
(of course all code pointing to my app and webpage is replaced for security reasons)

--`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=0123456789011121&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access`--

--`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access`--

and got:

```
http://www.example.com/?code=XXXXX1x1X1xxXxxX1xXxXxX1X111xX11XXXXX1XXXXXxX_XxXxxXxX1xxxXx1xXxXx-x1XxXXXxXXx1xXxXXXxXl1xX-111xXxxxXxxx1xXxxx1xXx1X1X1Xx-xxxXXXxXXXX1XXXXxx1Xxx1_xXxXxxxXx1x1XxXxxXx1XXxX-x1x1xxxXXxXxX1XX1XX1x1-xxXxxxx1Xx1XxXXXxxX#_=_
```

in other words(as I believe), retrieved the code:

```
XXXXX1x1X1xxXxxX1xXxXxX1X111xX11XXXXX1XXXXXxX_XxXxxXxX1xxxXx1xXxXx-x1XxXXXxXXx1xXxXXXxXl1xX-111xXxxxXxxx1xXxxx1xXx1X1X1Xx-xxxXXXxXXXX1XXXXxx1Xxx1_xXxXxxxXx1x1XxXxxXx1XXxX-x1x1xxxXXxXxX1XX1XX1x1-xxXxxxx1Xx1XxXXXxxX#_=_
```

As I have found on Google, it seems as I need to get another code as well, so then I have visited this URL(of course I have tried the first code I got first):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=0123456789011121&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&client_secret=1x1111xx11111xXXx11x111111111x11&code=XXXXX1x1X1xxXxxX1xXxXxX1X111xX11XXXXX1XXXXXxX_XxXxxXxX1xxxXx1xXxXx-x1XxXXXxXXx1xXxXXXxXl1xX-111xXxxxXxxx1xXxxx1xXx1X1X1Xx-xxxXXXxXXXX1XXXXxx1Xxx1_xXxXxxxXx1x1XxXxxXx1XXxX-x1x1xxxXXxXxX1XX1XX1x1-xxXxxxx1Xx1XxXXXxxX#_=_
```

--`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_I_GOT_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_RUN`--

But when i try to run the app I get this error message:
Result: `{"error":{"message":"Malformed access token XXXXX1x1X1xxXxxX1xXxXxX1X111xX11XXXXX1XXXXXxX_XxXxxXxX1xxxXx1xXxXx-x1XxXXXxXXx1xXxXXXxXl1xX-111xXxxxXxxx1xXxxx1xXx1X1X1Xx-xxxXXXxXXXX1XXXXxx1Xxx1_xXxXxxxXx1x1XxXxxXx1XXxX-x1x1xxxXXxXxX1XX1XX1x1-xxXxxxx1Xx1XxXXXxxX#_=_","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}`

I have tried with different types of the ending of the access token(#*=*), because I dont recognize it from the other, working access token I retrieved last week, to a fully working app that I have built. That one did not have that ending, as I remember.

I also post the script here, if that is of any interest. I have found it in a tutorial, and it is quite simple code:

```
<?php
    // CURL function to send with post method
    function send_post_curl($url, $postdata = “”) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $data = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $data;
    }
    // setup the message
    $fburl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/THE_FB_PAGE_ID/feed';
    $fbtoken = 'THE_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    $fbmsg = 'Great API to auto status, this is the message.
    Thank to WebDDR
    http://webddr.net/tips-and-tricks/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step-explanation/';
    $fbpcurl = 'access_token='. $fbtoken;
    $fbpcurl .= '&message='. str_replace('&', 'and', urlencode($fbmsg)) ;
    $result = send_post_curl($fburl, $fbpcurl);
    echo 'Result: '. $result;
?>
```

I really hope someone can help me, I am doing this as an job I have choosen to do for my education at the university.
/Johan
PS.
Sorry, had to wrangle with the links, --link-- because the forum thought it was spam
Ds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
session_start();   
$facebook_appid         = "facebook_appid";                                 // Facebook appplication id
$facebook_secret        = "facebook_secret";                // Facebook secret id
$redirect_uri           = "https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
$scope                  = "user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence,offline_access,manage_pages,publish_stream,user_events,friends_events"; // User permission for facebook

$code                   = $_REQUEST["code"]?$_REQUEST["code"]:"";

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state']  = time(); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url         = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&state=". $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=".$scope;
    header("location:".$dialog_url);
}

if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] == $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $token_url          = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?". "client_id=" . $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri). "&client_secret=" . $facebook_secret . "&code=" . $code;
    $response           = @file_get_contents($token_url);

    $params             = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);


    echo $params['access_token'];
    echo "<br>";

    //$offer_url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$dt->id."/conversations?access_token=".$dt->access_token;
    //$off              = @file_get_contents($offer_url);
    //$dto              = json_decode($off);

    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($dto);


}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I'm still getting the same error message: {"error":{"message":"Malformed access token XXX... ...xxX#_=_","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}

Comment: edited the code added session_start(); now try this code is worked for me

Comment: You need to give $redirect_uri same as your "site url" in app settings

Comment: I checked now so I had made it that way, and that was correct. It's strange, I've got 2 other apps with access_tokens, and they both works. I am happy that You are trying to help me!

Comment: Cool.. so you fixed it. :)

Comment: Oh, no, i didn't, but I checked so that $redirect_uri was correctly configured, and it was. But I still get the same error message:( What I mean is, that Your script gives me an access_token, but when I insert it in my script and run it, it gives me the same error message as before.

Comment: It is strange try this link  http://210.212.195.110/facebook_login/fb_proxy/fb_login/1 i implemented same code here.

Comment: If it doesn't works.. It will be problem with your server or internet connection

Comment: It works when I connect to Your app, but I can't make it work here. My other apps works fine, and they are at the same server. If you take a look at your access token, how does it look? Mine looks different in the end, than my other access tokens: f9p_BWxMyKS-nlg#_=_ The end: #_=_ appears now, but I dont have that ending on the other access tokens. May it be something with that? I have tried with cuttin off that end, but it does not work nether.

Comment: Yess! I got it working! I created an token via http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/596312707049764/?method=GET&path=1101538132%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname and it works! It does not have that #_=_ ending. It is just valid for a few hours, but I canexchange it to a more long-lived access token on that page. Now I only wish that I could generate one by script, myself... But I got one more step on the way anyway!

Comment: I could also exchange the short-lived access token to a more long-lived with this link: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&fb_exchange_token=OLD_SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN